Clarification on Theorem 6 from Uniswap V1 Formalized Model: $e_0 < e_2$ and $t_0 < t_2$
I have been studying the formalized model of Uniswap V1 from the whitepaper and the accompanying formalized model document (left the links below in the references).
Specifically, I am focusing on Theorem 6, which states:

If $\mathsf{addLiquidity_{code}}$ is subsequently followed by $\mathsf{removeLiquidity_{code}}$ as follows: $$(e_0,t_0,l_0)\xrightarrow{addLiquidity_{code}(\Delta e)}(e_1,t_1,l_1)\xrightarrow{removeLiquidity_{code}(\Delta l)}(e_2,t_2,l_2)$$
and $\Delta l =l_1-l_0$, then we have:
$$1. e_0<e_2$$
$$2. t_0<t_2$$
$$3. l_0=l_2$$

Here are the relevant formulas for $\mathsf{addLiquidity_{code}}$ and $\mathsf{removeLiquidity_{code}}$ from the paper:
$\mathsf{addLiquidity_{code}}$:
$$(e,t,l)\xrightarrow{\text{addLiquidity}_{code}(\Delta e)}(e',t',l')$$
where:
$$e'=e+\Delta e \\ t'= t + \left\lfloor \frac{\Delta e \cdot t}{e} \right\rfloor + 1
\\
l_1 = l + \left\lfloor \frac{\Delta e \cdot l}{e} \right\rfloor
$$
$\mathsf{removeLiquidity_{code}}$:
$$(e,t,l)\xrightarrow{\text{removeLiquidity}_{code}(\Delta l)}(e'',t'',l'')$$
where:
$$e''= e -  \left\lfloor \frac{\Delta l \cdot e}{l} \right\rfloor \\ t''= t -  \left\lfloor \frac{\Delta l \cdot t}{l} \right\rfloor
\\
l'' = l-\Delta l
$$
While I was able to convince myself that $l_0 = l_2$ holds true, I have doubts about the inequality $e_0 < e_2$. Specifically, I believe that $e_0 \le e_2$ because in the case where $\left(\frac{\Delta e}{e_0}\right) \cdot l_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, we would get equality.
However, my main difficulty is in deriving $t_0 < t_2$. Could this also be $t_0 \le t_2$? I have tried to prove this, but I am struggling with the expressions involving the floor functions. Really hope to get some help here.
References:

a link to the parent site
Formalized Model Document

